# Capacitor charge formula solved respect to t, R, C

Tags: capacitor, charge

I solved the capacitor's charge formula solved respect to t, R and C but according to the mathematics I find negative sign. As I know does not exists a negative time, resistance and capacitance, so which is the right way to write the formula (respect to t, R and C)? Is it mathematically right to remove the negative sign or to put the formula in absolute value?

[image]

Comment: ok. The expression (1-VC/VS) is always less than 1. From mathematics we know that ln(x) where 0<x<1 is negative. So the two negative signs will cancel out and you'll end up with t positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that your original formula applies to discharging a capacitor, and applies for t > 0.

Since the capacitor is discharging, Vc is always less than Vs, so Vc/Vs lies in the interval 0 to 1, so (1-Vc/Vs) also lies in this interval. As a result, ln of (1-Vc/Vs) is always negative, and this cancels the minus sign in your final equations.